# Fastest way of persisting a stream of big data (structured data) into a Snowflake table

Tags: performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for a way to programatically persist a stream of big data (structured data) into a Snowflake table in the fastest way possible.

I'm currently persisting my streaming data from Vertica which has the ultra-fast Vertica copy stream API.

I would like my data to be stored directly into a Snowflake table (not staged) in a structured format (not semi-structured).

I'm aware of the following options:

1. JDBC batch insert
2. Snowflake Kafka connector
3. Transfer data directly from the stream to an internal stage (PUT
   command) + Snowpipe for loading into the table

Are there any faster options available?

Comment: Pretty much all of those options do the same thing, which is generate files, copy them to S3, and then run a COPY INTO statement.  The key to improving the rate of data load is to make sure you are creating files that are ~100MB in size and then running the COPY INTO once using the correct size warehouse (based on the number of files to load).

Comment: +1 to what Mike said, plus a peak into the future: https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowflake-streaming-now-hiring-help-design-and-build-the-future-of-big-data-and-stream-processing/

Comment: As "the devil in the details", especially when it comes to performance, I would suggest looking into the differences between Bulk Load and SnowPipe, in particular the considerations made in regards to 'Recommended Load File Size' and 'Estimating Snowpipe Latency' https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-intro.html#how-is-snowpipe-different-from-bulk-data-loading

Comment: By "fastest" do you mean with the lowest latency or with the greatest throughput? i.e. how quickly can you load a single record from the moment it is available or how fast can you load a dataset of 1 million records?